# Make onPreExecute and onProgressUpdate common for all Asynctask Class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Currently , I am working in android application , in that I have 10 separate Asynctask Class for 10  separate operation , in that , the user defined function called inside onPreExecute() and onProgressUpdate() will be same for all 10 Asynctask Class. Is there any other way to simplify this . For example , I have an user defined function named "ADD" ,  and as of now , I have called the "ADD" function in onPreExecute() of all 10 Asynctask Class , is there any other way to simplify this , by using interface or any-other else,

Answer (score 3):

Create One Class that is BaseAsyncTask which extends AsyncTask.
And write implementation of your both  onPreExecute() and onProgressUpdate() int this.

```
public abstract class BaseAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

        @android.support.annotation.Nullable
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
        public Activity activity;

        public BaseAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity, R.style.CustomProgressSpinner);
            CommonUtilities.showDialog(progressDialog,activity);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            CommonUtilities.dismissDialog(progressDialog);
        }
    }
```

And in extend that BaseAsyncTask in your all AsyncTask.

```
public class AttachmentLoadTask extends BaseAsyncTask<DocumentVO, Void, File> {@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(DocumentVO... documentVOs) {
        File file = null;
        return file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(File file) {

        super.onPostExecute(file);

    }}
```

Comment: Well your answer is much better ;) couldn't do it better

Answer (score 0):

Create a basic async task with the operations in onPreExecute() and onProgressExecute(). Then create your async task classes (extend from the basic async task).

Answer (score 0):

surely , you may create a single class for all Asynctask calls

just create a class

```
 public class MyConnectionClass extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Boolean> {
    MyAsyncInterface delegate = null;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
    String output;

    public MyConnectionClass(MyAsyncInterface myAsyncInterface) {
        delegate = myAsyncInterface;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        delegate.processFinish(output);
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Uri... uris) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(uris[0].toString());
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String line = null;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);

            }
            output = builder.toString();
            return true;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            output = e.getMessage();
            return false;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            output = e.getMessage();
            return false;

        } finally {
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }

    }
}
```

and declare an interface like this

```
 public interface MyAsyncInterface {
    void processFinish(String output);
}
```

then create a Uri in your activity and implement MyAsyncInterface then inside the onPostExecute call processFinish and pass the output to the processFinish(String output) method present in your calling activity